# LINQ not returning desired data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to write a very simple method which will match userId & return the corresponding imagepath string. My code is something like this:

```
public string GetImagePath(int _ID)
{
 var imagepath=from s in context.Userinfoes
               where s.UserID==_ID
               select s.UserImage;
 return imagepath.ToString();
}
```

The problem is the linq is not loading the data, rather its loading a string like "system.data.object.objectquery1[system.string]"! I wrote similar methods many times before but getting this problem for the first time.

FYKI:

I'm using a 3 tier architecture & updated my edmx before doing this. I removed my reference & added them again to solve the problem but didn't work.

Please help.

Comment: linq not return a value, it return an object or list object

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in `return imagepath.ToString()` imagepath is not a data. It is IQueriable. So ToString() returns "system.data.object.objectquery1[system.string]".
Before this code you need to iterate your query. So try this:

```
public string GetImagePath(int _ID)
{
    var imagepath=from s in context.Userinfoes
           where s.UserID==_ID
           select s.UserImage;

    return imagepath.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I thought since there is only one data, so it won't need to iterate. Thanks.

Comment: If it is only one, then you should call Single() or SingleOrDefault()

Comment: May be not related to this question, can you give me an idea how to impose size restriction on uploaded image in terms of height & width. I mean, whatever the height & width of the uploaded image, I want show them according to my allocated size but full image should be shown. It would be great help. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you to search it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use Single()/First() to return one item from the enumerable list